# AIRFLOW_SCHEDULER_RUN_DURATION set up and scheduler doesn't restart when down

Tags: docker, airflow, amazon-ecs, airflow-scheduler

I am experiencing scheduler down suddenly and without a pattern.

I run `Airflow 2.1.2` in `AWS ECS` using `docker.

I know it's a [reported issue in Airflow docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.0.0/production-deployment.html#scheduler-uptime)

We set up `AIRFLOW__SCHEDULER__RUN_DURATION = 3600` to force the scheduler to restart every hour and avoid this way the scheduler is down suddenly.

But despite that, we see the last heartbeat was received 9 hours ago. Why is this happening?
The issue here is not the airflow scheduler is down, but the `ENV` variable to force the restart didn't work.

Can something avoid the airflow scheduler restart? Should we use `airflow.cfg` instead of the `env variable`?

**Edit**
I paste the var name wrong in here, but I have the correct name.

```
AIRFLOW__SCHEDULER__RUN_DURATION
```

I print the var value in `docker container`:

```
echo $AIRFLOW__SCHEDULER__RUN_DURATION

It returns 3600
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah - since you are at `2.1.2` - the `run_duration` parameter has been removed from Airflow 2:

You will not find it here:

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html

I think the best way to approach it is to identify why you have scheduler failing - it is not expected for it to be failing randomly, I guess you can dig in in the log files of scheduler and find the reason?

Comment: run_durations has been removed? What about: airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/… Still there the Scheduler Uptime section.

Can be this exception the one that cause that scheduler goes down?

airflow.exceptions.SerializedDagNotFound: DAG 'DWH-EXT-Appsflyer' not found in serialized_dag table.

In the UI dont find the dag, but I find it in the DB, dag table. Could be that dag has not been correctly deleted and scheduler is doing something despite it is not active?

Comment: Found other threads were they have the dag serialization issue and scheduler went down after that. I paused 4 dags that were not active but they weren't paused.

Should this avoid this crash? Or it's better to delete from DB all dags that are not in UI?

Which one is the difference between active and pause? Do the UI ON/OFF button makes reference to active, right? How to pause from UI?

Comment: You have questions for about A few stack overflow questions. I have no idea what the ansawers are. But naybe you should firs dig in the logs and find some reasons why scheduler is shutting down and if you can't find it, post a question with detailed logs ?

Comment: Yes I posted the related one into a new question, but anyways airfow docs:

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/production-deployment.html#scheduler-uptime

Still showing the Scheduler Uptime section that speaks about scheduler hanging, maybe this page need and update.

About finding some reasons why scheduler down i posted in the first comment: 
 airflow.exceptions.SerializedDagNotFound

Comment: Absolutley - feel free to make A PR to update this part. It's super easy - just click at the "suggest a change on this page" and you will be able to create PR using GitHub UI - no development environment needed. It's very easy - Airflow is created by the comunity so such contributions are most welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the wrong variable name:

`AIRFLOW__SCHEDULER__RUN_DURATION` is the right one - note double `_` after AIRFLOW and SCHEDULER

Comment: Yes sorry, it was a typo when pasting here. I mean: AIRFLOW__SCHEDULER__RUN_DURATION. I edit the post to fix the typo.

Comment: I also added the print value that i get from env variable in docker container